# how to calculate battery time,3g game play etc,iOS

Tags: iphone, ipad

i want to calculate time for 
3D gaming,3G Talk time,Video use,WiFi Internet,2G Talk time,Audio use and Standby depending on the current battery level.
There are many app do this, but i didnt found any resource to calculate that in iOS.

I calculated the battery level

> [myDevice setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];
>       float batLeft = [myDevice batteryLevel];
>       int i=[myDevice batteryState];
>
> ```
> int batinfo=(batLeft*100);
> ```

now on the basis of batinfo,i need to calculate the time remaining for other parameters.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apple provide some data in device specification. You can use it for your calculation.

For example Apple say, app. 8 hours talk time on 3G ([Iphone 5](http://www.apple.com/iphone/specs.html)).
Now,

```
int batinfo=(batLeft*100);
int minutes3G=480; //minutes of 8 hour (static)

int talk3G=(minutes3G*batinfo)/100; 
hour=talk3G/60;
min=talk3G%60;
lbl3Gtalk.text=[lbl3Gtalk.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"Remaining Time : %dh %dmin",hour,min];
```