# Get the value in percentage

Tags: iphone, ipad, percentage

I am using below to get the time remaining for playing games on iPhone.

> int minutes_games_iPhone5 = 600;//minutes of 10 hour (static)
>
> ```
>     int games_iPhone5=(minutes_games_iPhone5*batteryinfo)/100;
>     int hour_game_iPhone5 = games_iPhone5/60;
>     int min_game_iPhone5 = games_iPhone5%60;
> ```
>
> log :hour:min =  8:30

Which works well, i guess.Now i need to figure out how can i show the same output in percentage,like 50%.

So 8:30 should also represent the value in percentage.How can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001165/how-to-calculate-battery-time-3g-game-play-etc-ios?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8 hour 30 mintues equals to 8*60 + 30= 480+30=510min

Total time is 600min.

Therefore % is 510/600*100.

Convert this thing to code you will get the percent.

But use double/float otherwise you may end up with 0*100 in (510/600=0). Make it 510.0/600.

Comment: oh yes, i m ending up with 0. anyother way to get the value,without converting it to float?